# Why akka actor use ActorRef as paramater's type rather then the type itselfs?

Tags: akka, actor

I have read many example of definition of actors class to build a program. What I notice is all of them use `ActorRef` as paramaters type. For example,

```
class LogProcessor(dbWriter: ActorRef)
    extends Actor with ActorLogging with LogParsing {

    import LogProcessor._

    def receive = {
      case LogFile(file) =>
        val lines: Vector[DbWriter.Line] = parse(file)
        lines.foreach(dbWriter ! _)
    }
}
```

the `dbWriter`'s actual type is `DBWriter` defined as:

```
class DbWriter(databaseUrl: String) extends Actor {
    val connection = new DbCon(databaseUrl)

    import DbWriter._
    def receive = {
      case Line(time, message, messageType) =>
        connection.write(Map('time -> time,
          'message -> message,
          'messageType -> messageType))
    }

    override def postStop(): Unit = {
      connection.close() 
    }
  }
```

At the example, why not use `DbWriter` as dbWriter's type?
If we use `ActorRef` anywhere, out program just look like a weak type system.
Besides, Akka actor use `actorOf` method to create child actor and it return ActorRef.I also confuse why not return the real type of the actor?

Comment: All of this is explained in the Akka docs: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/general/actors.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some comments about actors:

- We can create many instances of an Actor by calling actorOf or actorFor
- We assign a different name to any actor instance we create
- Calling actorOf will return an ActorRef that points to that instance
- You only communicate with an Actor's instance by sending messages through its ActorRef, that way the actor instance is encapsulated and there is no way to access its internal state
- Using the ActorRef allows you to communicate with local or remote  actors
- Each actor(child) has one parent(another actor), the parent is the one who created the actor using actorOf
- The parent decides the supervision strategy of its children
- Usually, you create one instance of an actor and share the resulting ActorRef with other actors who wish to communicate with that actor

Comment: I think the key is fourth one and other refers can be also works if use real type because real type is subclass of `ActorRef`.

Comment: Besides, I really hope Akka Actor need a IDE/Code tips to track the ActorRef where it was defined.